# The 'cvlib' distribution was not found and is required by the application in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cvlib

I am using **cvlib** package in my python project. 
If I run python file in Linux command line its work fine without any error.

I want make it executable one file for Linux. I used **PyInstaller** packaged it. When run its throwing

**The 'cvlib' distribution was not found and is required by the application**

I am using :

**1. Python : 3.6**

**2. PyInstaller : 3.5.**

**3. Cvlib: 0.2.2**

**4. Flask: 1.1.1.**

Comment: Your issue looks similar to this [https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1713]. Maybe consider adding a hook file to force pyinstaller to include cvlib?

Comment: @AdityaSantoso where do I need to hook, In python file or .spec file?

Comment: My understanding is you need to create a separate python file and import it as transitive dependency on your actual python file, or you can add the hook on existing python file. Whatever needed to nudge pyinstaller to think that it's a transitive dependency